# Rails access hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing around with Netflix's [Workflowable](https://github.com/Netflix/Workflowable) gem. Right now I'm working on making a custom action where the user can choose choices.

I end up pulling `{"id":1,"value":"High"}` out with `@options[:priority][:value]`

What I want to do is get the id value of 1. Any idea how to pull that out? I tried `@options[:priority][:value][:id]` but that seems to through an error.

Here's what the action looks like/how I'm logging the value:

```
class Workflowable::Actions::UpdateStatusAction < Workflowable::Actions::Action
  include ERB::Util
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  NAME="Update Status Action"
  OPTIONS = {
      :priority => {
        :description=>"Enter priority to set result to",
        :required=>true,
        :type=>:choice,
        :choices=>[{id: 1, value: "High"} ]
      }
    }

  def run
    Rails.logger.debug @options[:priority][:value]
  end

end
```

Here's the error:

```
Error (3a7b2168-6f24-4837-9221-376b98e6e887): TypeError  in ResultsController#flag
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Here's what `@options[:priority]` looks like:

```
{"description"=>"Enter priority to set result to", "required"=>true, "type"=>:choice, "choices"=>[{"id"=>1, "value"=>"High"}], "value"=>"{\"id\":1,\"value\":\"High\"}", "user_specified"=>true}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@options[:priority]["value"]` looks to be a strong containing json, not a hash. This is why you get an error when using `[:id]` (this method doesn't accept symbols) and why `["id"]` returns the string "id".

You'll need to parse it first, for example with `JSON.parse`, at which point you'll have a hash which you should be able to access as normal. By default the keys will be strings so you'll need

JSON.parse(value)["id"]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is something like `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

It looks like `@options[:priority]` is a hash with keys `:id` and `:value`.  So you would want to use `@options[:priority][:id]` (lose the `:value` that returns the string).

Comment: You assume correctly - I updated the post with the error. However, when I do `@options[:priority][:id]` it ends up logging a blank line