# Ruby on Rails - Array of Hashes - Display value based on key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, hash

I have an array of hashes saved to a Rails 5 Postgres DB (Ruby 2.3.1). I’m able to display this on my `show.html.erb` page like so:

```
 <%= @item.yearly_interest_totals %>
```

This displays:

```
[
 "{:financial_year=>\"2017\", :total=>\"120.08\"}",
 "{:financial_year=>\"2018\", :total=>\"237.32\"}",
 "{:financial_year=>\"2019\", :total=>\"163.75\"}",
 "{:financial_year=>\"2020\", :total=>\"87.95\"}",
 "{:financial_year=>\"2021\", :total=>\"15.38\"}"
]
```

Also on this page I have a variable `<%= fin_year %>` which displays `2017`.

I’m trying to display the value corresponding to this `fin_year` key in the view, with the following code, but it is giving me a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error…

```
<%= @item.yearly_interest_totals.detect do |t|
 t[:financial_year] == fin_year end [:total] %>
```

Could somebody please explain why i'm receiving this error?

**Update**

Both the hash key and local variable being named the same is confusing, I have changed the local variable to `fin_year`.

<%= fin_year.class %> is producing `String`

<%= @item.yearly_interest_totals.class %> is producing `Array`

<%= @item.yearly_interest_totals[0][:financial_year].class %> is returning a "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error...

Comment: It might have something to do with `financial_year` being a variable and symbol. Try changing the variable to `fin_year` or something else. Also, what does `<%= financial_year.class %>` and `<%= @item.yearly_interest_totals[0][:financial_year].class %>` show?

Comment: Also, I might change `t[:financial_year]` to `t["financial_year"]`. Not sure why but it's weird sometimes with me.

Comment: @RyanK Most definitely confusing - I've changed the local variable and updated above. I've also edited the above to display what `.class` on both is giving me ...

Comment: What about changing `t[:financial_year]` to `t["financial_year"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the values for the keys `:financial_year` in your array of hashes are strings (e.g. "2017"), but your value for the variable `financial_year` is a fixnum/integer (e.g 2017). Try making them consistent to compare, such as:

```html
<%= @item.yearly_interest_totals.detect do |t|
  t[:financial_year] == financial_year.to_s end [:total] %>
```

Here is output from the Rails console comparing the two:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 15647
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)

2.3.3 :001 > item_yearly_interest_totals = [{ financial_year: "2017", total: "120.08" }, { financial_year: "2018", total: "237.32" }, { financial_year: "2019", total: "163.75" }, { financial_year: "2020", total: "87.95" }, { financial_year: "2021", total: "15.38" }]
=> [{:financial_year=>"2017", :total=>"120.08"}, {:financial_year=>"2018", :total=>"237.32"}, {:financial_year=>"2019", :total=>"163.75"}, {:financial_year=>"2020", :total=>"87.95"}, {:financial_year=>"2021", :total=>"15.38"}]

2.3.3 :002 > financial_year = 2017
=> 2017

2.3.3 :003 > item_yearly_interest_totals.detect do |t|
2.3.3 :004 >      t[:financial_year] == financial_year end [:total]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  .
  .
  .

2.3.3 :005 > item_yearly_interest_totals.detect do |t|
2.3.3 :006 >      t[:financial_year] == financial_year.to_s end [:total]
=> "120.08"

2.3.3 :007 >
```

---

**UPDATE (02-20-2017)**

I don't completely understand where the distinction within Rails lies or is occurring that is the source of your issue, but even though you execute `@item.yearly_interest_totals[0].class` and you get `Hash`, you can't seem to access the values using a hash key (e.g. [:financial_year], ["financial_year"], etc.).

After some digging, I found this:
[Rails access hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804648/rails-access-hash-value)
and the accepted answer led me to try `JSON.parse`, which I was able to get working, albeit with `.each` rather than `.detect`. This time I did, in a Rails 5 app, create an `Item` model, used Postgres, and seeded a single `Item`. What I still did not do is create a controller or any views. I executed my code through the Rails console. So, if you duplicate my code and it does not work for you, the problem may lie there, within the controller and views.

Ultimately, there is still some discovery to be done regarding this hash/JSON distinction and how implementation leads it to manifest as one or the other.

**app/models/item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**db/migrate/20170220221004_enable_hstore_extension.rb**

```
class EnableHstoreExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension 'hstore'
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170220221129_create_item.rb**

```
class CreateItem < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, index: { unique: true }
      t.hstore :yearly_interest_totals, array: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**db/seeds.rb**

```
Item.create(name: 'Sample Item', yearly_interest_totals: [{ financial_year: "2017", total: "120.08" }, { financial_year: "2018", total: "237.32" }, { financial_year: "2019", total: "163.75" }, { financial_year: "2020", total: "87.95" }, { financial_year: "2021", total: "15.38" }])
```

And here is the code as it is executed in the Rails console:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 19764
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)

2.4.0 :001 > @item = Item.first
Item Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Item id: 1, name: "Sample Item", yearly_interest_totals: [{"total"=>"120.08", "financial_year"=>"2017"}, {"total"=>"237.32", "financial_year"=>"2018"}, {"total"=>"163.75", "financial_year"=>"2019"}, {"total"=>"87.95", "financial_year"=>"2020"}, {"total"=>"15.38", "financial_year"=>"2021"}], created_at: "2017-02-20 22:25:14", updated_at: "2017-02-20 22:25:14">
2.4.0 :002 > @item.class
=> Item(id: integer, name: string, yearly_interest_totals: hstore, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
2.4.0 :003 > @item.yearly_interest_totals.class
=> Array
2.4.0 :004 > @item.yearly_interest_totals[0].class
=> Hash

2.4.0 :005 > financial_year = 2017
=> 2017
2.4.0 :006 > financial_year.class
=> Integer

2.4.0 :007 > selected_year_interest_total = nil
=> nil
2.4.0 :008 > selected_year_interest_total.class
=> NilClass

2.4.0 :009 > @item.yearly_interest_totals.each do |t|
2.4.0 :010 >   puts JSON.parse(t["financial_year"]).class
2.4.0 :011 >   if JSON.parse(t["financial_year"]) == financial_year
2.4.0 :012?>     selected_year_interest_total = JSON.parse(t["total"])
2.4.0 :013?>   end
2.4.0 :014?> end
Integer
Integer
Integer
Integer
Integer
=> [{"total"=>"120.08", "financial_year"=>"2017"}, {"total"=>"237.32", "financial_year"=>"2018"}, {"total"=>"163.75", "financial_year"=>"2019"}, {"total"=>"87.95", "financial_year"=>"2020"}, {"total"=>"15.38", "financial_year"=>"2021"}]

2.4.0 :015 > selected_year_interest_total
=> 120.08
2.4.0 :016 > selected_year_interest_total.class
=> Float
```

Comment: I've just updated the above and it appears the financial_year / fin_year local variable is of type String, but the Hash values are returning an error as above. Have you seen this before? Cheers

Comment: The `fin_year` variable is created earlier in a  `<% @item.repayments.group_by… %>` block. I’m then checking the class type of `fin_year` after it is assigned a value, inside this `.group_by` block...

Comment: Caveats to this comment - First, since I recreated your problem just using variables and not setting up a model and database like you have, I can't be sure whether or not the issue has to do with your model/database/migration implementation. Second, some of what I'll suggest is demonstrated with Rails 4, not 5, but hopefully will still apply. That being said, I'm assuming your Item class migration has something like: t.hstore :yearly_interest_totals, array: true. If so, look at the section labeled "Query" in this post: https://inopinatus.org/2013/07/12/using-arrays-of-hstore-with-rails-4/

Comment: Create a scope like the "where_any" one in that post, then use it as it is used there on your @item to see if it returns the total for your desired year.

Comment: Okay I had a column type of Array, not Hstore. I followed your example above and it works a treat - thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about Rails 5 but maybe this will help, Rails 4, assuming that financial_year is a variable and I am understanding the question correctly:

```
<% @item.yearly_interest_totals.each do |t| %>
<%= t['total'] == financial_year %>
<% end %>
```